# Unable to use urllib2 module in vim script

Tags: python, vim

I am unable to use urllib2 module in vim script:

```
if !has('python')
    finish
endif

function! PrintForecastInfo()

python << EOF

import urllib2

rp5_url = 'http://rp5.ru/'

response = urllib2.urlopen(rp5_url).read()

EOF
endfunc
```

This code gave me the following error:

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be
>   found

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

I'm using Windows 8 btw.

Comment: Do you have the necessary files that urllib2 may require on a lower level? Has urllib2 been installed via something like pip? Also, try putting "import urllib2" at the top of your document instead of in the middle (try doing that, run it and see what happens).

Comment: @Joe [`urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) is a python2 stdlib module, so it should be available with any ("non-stripped") interpreter

Comment: Thanks @Bakuriu , looks like the problem may just be in the code itself.

Comment: The code snippet works for me. Make sure that vim can use python commands (i.e. python is in your PATH. I don't know how to do this for windows). I have a feeling vim can't find python.

Comment: @FDinoff Yes, Python is in the PATH